# Avoid id generation in composite key using MapsId

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to create join table entity with additional column.
How to avoid composite id generation if one of the child entity was not persisted previously during join table entity persistence? I am using @MapsId to get parts of id's from the entities for the composite key.

When I am trying to save AssetRepositoryEntity with specified not persisted Repository(without generated RepositoryId) in it, I expect Exception or failure somehow in other way. But instead Hibernate trying to generate Id for not persisted Repository

This is parent entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "ASSET_REPO_MAP")
public class AssetRepoMapEntity implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private AssetRepositoryId primaryKey;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @MapsId("repositoryId")
    private RepositoryEntity repositoryEntity;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("assetId")
    private AssetEntity assetEntity;

    @Column(name = "STATUS", nullable = false)
    private Status status = Status.NEW;

    public AssetRepoMapEntity(){}

    public AssetRepoMapEntity(RepositoryEntity repositoryEntity, AssetEntity assetEntity){
        this.repositoryEntity = repositoryEntity;
        this.assetEntity = assetEntity;
        this.primaryKey = new AssetRepositoryId(repositoryEntity.getId(),assetEntity.getAssetId());
    }
................................................................
................................................................
```

It has composite key AssetRepository:

```java
@Embeddable
public class AssetRepositoryId implements Serializable{

    @Column(name="repository_id")
    private String repositoryId;

    @Column(name="asset_id")
    private String assetId;

    private AssetRepositoryId(){
    }

    public AssetRepositoryId(String repositoryId, String assetId){
        this.repositoryId = repositoryId;
        this.assetId = assetId;
    }
..................................................................
..................................................................
```

And Child entity RepositoryEntity:

```java
@Entity(name = "repositoryEntity-v2")
@Table(name = "REPOSITORIES")
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
public class RepositoryEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3440851562367009351L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "REPOSITORY_ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String repository_id;

    @Column(name = "description", length = 512, nullable = false)
    private String description;
.....................................................................
.....................................................................
    @Column(name = "status", length = 64)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status = Status.ACTIVE;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "repositoryEntity", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<AssetRepoMapEntity> assetRepositoryList = new HashSet<AssetRepoMapEntity>();
....................................................................
....................................................................
```

@MapsId provides RepositoryEntity.repository_id for AssetRepositoryId.repositoryId as far as I understood.
It also worth to mention that I am using JpaRepository in order to persist 
AssetRepoMapEntity:

```java
@Repository(value = "assetRepoMapRepository-v2")
public interface AssetRepoMapRepository extends JpaRepository<AssetRepoMapEntity, AssetRepositoryId> {
}
```

I am trying to persist AssetRepoMapEntity:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestConfiguration
public class AssetRepoMapTest {

    @Autowired
    private AssetRepository assetRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RepoRepository repoRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AssetRepoMapRepository assetRepoMapRepository;

    RepositoryEntity repositoryEntity;

    AssetEntity assetEntity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        repositoryEntity = new RepositoryEntity();
        repositoryEntity.setName("repository1");
        repositoryEntity.setDescription("repository1 description");
        repositoryEntity.setPath("/repository1/path");
        repositoryEntity.setStatus(RepositoryEntity.Status.ACTIVE);

        assetEntity = new AssetEntity();
        assetEntity.setKey("....");
        assetEntity.setType(.....);
    }

    @Test
    public void insertAssetItemWithNotExistingRepository() {
        assetRepository.save(assetEntity1);
        AssetRepoMapEntity assetJoinRepositoryEntity = new AssetRepoMapEntity(this.repositoryEntity1,assetEntity1);


        assetRepoMapRepository.save(assetJoinRepositoryEntity);

        Optional<AssetRepoMapEntity> result = assetRepoMapRepository.findById(assetJoinRepositoryEntity.getPrimaryKey());
    }

}
```

Expected result:

Exception, because RepositoryEntity was created but was not persisted(in transient state) and it's repository_id should be null

Actual result:
Hibernate tries to insert next record into the database in order to legalize persistence of "AssetRepoMapEntity":

```java
FE=> Parse(stmt=null,query="insert into repositories (status, repository_id) values ($1, $2)",oids={1043,1043})

o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  FE=> Bind(stmt=null,portal=null,$1=<'ACTIVE'>,type=VARCHAR,$2=<'3e3e31a2-9ba1-4863-843a-7b07ba30cf2b'>,type=VARCHAR)
```

1) It gives up previously created entity with all fields fulfilled

2) Generates new entity with only repository_id property field generated(all other properties are empty)

3) Trying to insert generated raw but ends up with exception because one of the rows should not be null. In this case description is not nullable.

Comment: i'd suppose, that if you remove `@DynamicInsert` and `@DynamicUpdate` from `RepositoryEntity` you will get what you want

Comment: No, as far as I know `@DynamicInsert` and `@DynamicUpdate` is for dynamic construction of requests on demand(not on startup time). But I have tried this advice. And it doesn't work for me. Here is the output.

Comment: FE=> Parse(stmt=null,query="insert into repositories (description, name, path, status, repository_id) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)",

Comment: And my goal is to prevent this insertion at all.